# Trying to understand where to configure Automapper in a .NET 6 Function App

Tags: azure-functions, automapper, .net-6.0

We are able to configure the profiles without issue:

```
  .ConfigureServices(s =>
                {
                    // AddAutoMapper - to load all automapper profiles
                    s.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
                })
```

And the profiles look correct and function:

```
    public class CreateRequestToBusinessMap : Profile
    {
        public CreateRequestToBusinessMap()
        {
            CreateMap<CreateRequest,Business>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SupplierCode,
                    opt => 
                        opt.MapFrom(src => src.supplier_id))
                .ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<CreateRequestContact, Contact>()
                .ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<CreateRequestMarket, Market>()
                .ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<CreateRequestSubscription, Subscription>()
                .ReverseMap();

        }
    }
```

Trying to figure out how to add global configurations to the .NET 6 Function App. Not sure what I am missing.  We are new to Automapper but the documentation is not clear on where to add the configuration. https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html#where-do-i-configure-automapper

Answer (score 2):

The **automapper** configuration is once per app domain so you should keep the **automapper** configuration code in the **startup class**  in azure functions.

If you will consider an asp.net application then it should be **Global.asax** file.

AutoMapper also supports ASP.NET Core's dependency injection feature out-of-the-box, which we can utilise in [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/).

For more information, please refer this references:

1. [Best Practices of AutoMapper using in Azure Functions](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-use-automapper-in-azure-functions/)
2. [AutoMapper Dependency Injection into Azure Functions](https://devkimchi.com/2019/01/02/automapper-di-into-azure-functions/)

Comment: My issue is around the fact that this is a .NET 6 Isolated Function App so there is no startup class.  Found a work around to create a base class for all my maps that has the configuration.